# Publishing asp.net single page to ftp server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, publish

i'm trying to publish a webpage into my ftp server, thing is when i publish it and try to access it, the result is just pure code . How can i make it so that only the "design" of the asp file appears?

Thanks in advance,
Bruno Charters

Answer (score 1):

> How can i make it so that only the "design" of the asp file appears?

If all you want to appear in the browser is the "design" (meaning no server-side logic). Then all you'd really need is an HTML page. To do so:

- copy the markup rendered by the `.aspx` file from the browsers source
- paste the markup into an appropriately named `.html`/`.htm` file
- upload the file to your server

If there is *server-side* logic then you'll need to upload the .aspx file to a server that has ***IIS*** and the appropriate version of the ***.NET Framework*** to run the page.

Comment: it has logic behind it, what is it with the IIS? I don't have access to the server computer, that means i must ask the server owner to update .net framework and the iis? after that is it just go into the the url and the page should load? thanks

Comment: yes, whatever version of the framework the page depends on to run also needs to be installed on the web server. there might be more configuration necessary and it is very difficult to provide a comprehensive solution to publishing a site without first knowing the server's configuration. having said that, i'd go with checking the framework version on the app pool first along with proper configurations on the site ...

Comment: And what's with the IIS thingie ? What's the purpose on it and how do i get it to work on the server ? it automatically assumes the asp file ?

Comment: learn the basics about iis before attempting to deploy a site — iis is to asp as apache is to php.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to compile your code before you publish it. Compiling your code basically moves all the logic into the .dll file and leave only the HTML (well, at least). You will still need  a Web Server with aspx processor, typically IIS.

You will need to point your Web Server to the folder you are uploading to.